# Installing 2 DDR3 Sticks in MB with 4 Slots

Tags: motherboard, ddr3

I just put together my first system that uses DDR3 memory.  The motherboard I got is an ASUS M4A77T/USB3 and it has 4 DDR3 RAM slots.  Looking in the manual for the MB it doesn't say anything about how to install the RAM as far as matching the pairs goes.

I have 2 4GB sticks of RAM, and whether I put the sticks next to each other (of the 4 RAM slots, there are two blue ones next to each other and 2 black ones next to each other) or space them apart, The BIOS still shows that I have 8GB installed.

I have been getting an IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD error, and have read in some other places that it could be hardware/RAM related.

Does the RAM need to go in the A1, A2 slots (different colored but both A), or the A1 B1 slots? (A1 B1 are both the lovely blue color.)

Any help would be awesome.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you memory configuration read page 1-14 of your manual, it tells you exactly which slots to use (color coded) for Single-sided or Double-sided RAM.  For your configuration it will not matter which color slots you use, just put both your sticks in either the blue slots, or both your sticks in the black slots.  Since you seem to have an affinity for the "lovely" color blue I would go with blue :)

Your BSOD error has nothing to do with *where* you are putting your RAM, but that is not to say your BOSD error is not caused by faulty RAM.  To begin diagnosis of your BSOD error I would run Memtest 86+ on your sticks of RAM one at a time, and it does not matter which slot you plug a single stick into when you do this test (since you will only have one stick plugged in).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I knew it should be something simple to figure out, I just couldn't understand why the computer recognized it as being there wherever I stuck it!  Also, I'll be running a Memtest on it this evening.  I really hope that solves my BSOD issue! THANKS AGAIN!